# Get Controller-instances from Routes.MapHttpRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, controller

In an existing C# Web project here at my Job I've added a Web API part.

In four of my own classes that I use for the Web API I need to access some of the existing Controller-classes. Right now I just create a new Instance of them and everything works as intented: `ProductController controller = new ProductController();`

Still, creating a new ProductController while one should already exist obviously isn't a good practice. I know the Controllers are created in the Config-file in the Routes.MapHttpRoute, since it's using the C# Web MVC method. Below I've copied that piece of code:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Default",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new[] { "MyProject.Controllers" }
);
route.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
```

I've tried to access these Controllers in my one of my API-classes like so:

```
private void getControllerInstance()
{
    var url = "~/Products";
    // Original path is stored and will be rewritten in the end
    var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    string originalPath = httpContext.Request.Path;

    try
    {
        // Fake a request to the supplied URL into the routing system
        httpContext.RewritePath(url);
        RouteData urlRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);

        // If the route data was not found (e.g url leads to another site) then authorization is denied.
        // If you want to have a navigation to a different site, don't use AuthorizationMenu
        if (urlRouteData != null)
        {
            string controllerName = urlRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();

            // Get an instance of the controller that would handle this route
            var requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContext, urlRouteData);
            var controllerFactory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
            // TODO: Fix error (The controller for path '/Products' was not found or does not implement IController.) on this line:
            var controllerbase = (ControllerBase)controllerFactory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
            controller = (ProductController)controllerbase;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Reset our request path.
        httpContext.RewritePath(originalPath);
    }
}
```

As you might have noticed by the TODO-comment, at the line `var controllerbase = (ControllerBase)controllerFactory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);`, I get the following error:

> HttpException was unhandler by user code: The controller for path '/Products' was not found or does not implement IController.

Does anyone know how to fix this error? Has this got something to do with one of the following two lines of the code in the Config-file?

```
namespaces: new[] { "MyProject.Controllers" }

route.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = false;
```

Or did I do something else wrong?

Comment: @chrfin Why did you remove the "C# Web" part in my question title? I always add the programming language in front of the question so people scrolling through stackoverflow questions can more easily see it's for C#. (I know this can also be seen at the tags, but isn't it easier to spot if it's also in the title?)

Comment: Tags should NOT be added to the title - thats SO "guidelines". If someone (like me) only wants C# question he can simply "click the tag" and get them filtered out. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging -> `Should I use tags in titles?`

Comment: @chrfin Thanks for the response and the link. Personally I find it more recognizable to have a tag in the title than below the question, but if it's stackoverflow's guidelines I'll adapt.

Comment: I had the same preference, but if you get used to this "tag system" you start to like it ;)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tip to everyone: Don't continue programming when you are very, very tired.. Anyway, everything was correct except for a small flaw:

My API Controller is called ProductsController and my normal (default) controller is called ProductController. In the method above I use:

```
var url = "~/Products";
```

To access the ProductController..

So, after removing the "s" (and for good measure make everything lower case) I have the following instead:

```
var url = "~/product";
```

And now it works..